# Инверсия цветов background-image для дополения Chrom

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Функция для инверсии цветов и текста.
двойная инверсия помогает не инвертировать цвета картинкок и видео, но не помогает с фоновым изображениями, вот часть кода

```
function invertColors() {
  const style = document.createElement("style");
  style.textContent = `
    html {
      filter: invert(100%);
      
      background: white !important;
    } 

    img, video {
      filter: invert(100%) !important;
    } 

  `;
  document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

пробовал по всякому, возможно, конечно, не так пробовал. Спасибо